# kafka to pyspark structured streaming, parsing json as dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am experimenting with spark structured streaming (spark v2.2.0) to consume json data from kafka. However I encountered the following error.

> pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: 'Missing required
>   configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no default
>   value.

Does anyone know why? The job was submitted using spark-submit below.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 sparksstream.py
```

This is the entire python script.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Define schema of json
schema = StructType() \
        .add("Session-Id", StringType()) \
        .add("TransactionTimestamp", IntegerType()) \
        .add("User-Name", StringType()) \
        .add("ID", StringType()) \
        .add("Timestamp", IntegerType())

# load data into spark-structured streaming
df = spark \
      .readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xxxx:9092") \
      .option("subscribe", "topicName") \
      .load() \
      .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value"))

# Print output
query = df.writeStream \
            .outputMode("append") \
            .format("console") \
            .start()
```

Comment: Did you get any progress on this one?

Comment: hi, not really~ i gave up and use another method instead of parsing as json~

Comment: @jake, my query is related to col function. I did not find any call function in function module. How you are able to use col function.

Comment: @Jake what method did you use? I am in your situation.

Answer (score -2):

use this instead to submit:

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$SPARK_HOME/jars/kafka-clients-1.1.0.jar"  \
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 \
sparksstream.py
```

Assuming that you have donwloaded the kafka-clients*jar in you $SPARK_HOME/jars folder